# Confluence not able to display iframe's content completely (CORS issues)

Tags: html, iframe, grafana, confluence, confluence-macros

I am using the "Raintank" website, which hosts public Grafana dashboards. Here is the iframe they give me:

```
<iframe src="https://snapshot.raintank.io/dashboard-solo/snapshot/lBtQQ...?orgId=2&from=1596254400000&to=1620432682439&panelId=16" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want to show this iframe within Confluence, so within Confluence, I did "insert more content - other macros - iframe". I put in an iframe link into there of "https://snapshot.raintank.io/dashboard-solo/snapshot/lBtQQ...?orgId=2&from=1596254400000&to=1620432682439&panelId=16".

After saving it, I see part of the iframe loads (I see a loading gif from the raintank site), but then its loading forever. Looking in the browse console, I see:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://snapshot.raintank.io/img/online.svg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Any idea how to get around this CORS issue?